# Using spring social with Wicket

Tags: wicket, spring-social

I am trying to implement Facebook login in my wicket application. I was going through Spring social and was wondering before continuing, can it be easily implemented with Wicket as it is some sort of Spring MVC like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not going to be easy to integrate something built for Spring MVC with Wicket, as they're radically different architectures.

[Wicket Facebook project](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Facebook) looks like a good start at what you need, though I can't really vouch for it as I've never tried this.

Comment: That what I was thinking about using spring social. I have never tried out Wicket facebook also, but I was trying to implement https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/adding-facebook-connect.html but nothing is happening. No FB login UI is visible to me.